# Modifying object fields in other fragment/dialog without any callbacks?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Lately Ive noticed that in some parts of my app, I really dont need to use any interface callback from one Fragment to another/to parent activity whenever I modify a field in an object.

Just to make a clear example, lets say I have this class:

```
class Foo {
public String field;
}
```

The user has set this field to "Hello" but wishes to modify it and set it as "Hi!". Currently I would launch a dialog/show another fragment where the user can input this new value. After he is done a callback will be dispatched and the parent activity/other fragment where the user previously was will get notified that the field has changed and update the object accordingly.

HOWEVER. What Ive noticed is that I dont need the callback, the object reference is the same and after returning the field will be "Hi!" even without the callback.

Is this "safe" and reliable? Can I trust that this system will work 100% of the time?

I understand that this will not work when doing the modifying part in another activity.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`callback` here is helping you keep less dependency between fragment and another fragment/activity.

One of the advantage of using a fragment is re-usability, but if you share objects between a fragment and an activity then that fragment might not be useful for other activities.

A good callback mechanism will help you make decoupled and re-usable fragments.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I am re-using fragments wherever possible. Im just curious about this specific case and if it works.